# Check Internet connection in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In some applications, like `WhatsApp`, when I send a message with no internet connection then close(terminate) the app, the message will be sent when internet comes back.

I'm trying to do the same thing and I wonder if there is any way to check for an internet connection when my app is not running and in the foreground in order to do a specific task.

Comment: It sounds like you need [background app refresh](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh) if you'd like to send the message later while the app is not in the foreground.

Comment: But i think background app refresh work while app open not when terminated

Comment: The system will relaunch an app from the ["terminated" state](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7) unless the user **force quits** it. If the app was terminated by the system or even because of a device reboot, your app will be relaunched into the background.

Answer (score 4):

[Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Example:

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {
    // not reachable
} else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) {
    // reachable via Wifi
} else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN) {
    // reachable via WWAN
}
```

Edit

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Initialize Reachability
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // Start Monitoring
    [reachability startNotifier];

    //your code

    return YES;
}
```

Every time the network interface changes, `reachabilityDidChange:` is invoked

```
- (void)reachabilityDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{

    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {
        // not reachable
    } else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) {
        // reachable via Wifi
    } else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN) {
        // reachable via WWAN
    }
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: this code may work will app open but i wonder there is any way to handle that when app close(terminate).